# Create Views in Sharepoint that allows me to view documents due for review based on last review date column

Tags: 2010, document, view

We have multiple documents(not stored in SharePoint) for which we monitor the review dates in SharePoint as a part of our document management system.

The information of document is stored in a list. We have multiple columns in that list.

Two of the columns are of type date: Last review date and Next Review date.

I would like to create a view that shows:

- Documents due for review in the next 60 days based on the last review date.
- Documents that don't have a review date (We have documents that are draft and therefore don't have a last review date).

Any help appreciated or suggestions.

Comment: Do you want to show the documents due for review from 60 days of last review date or the next 60 days from today?

Comment: And how do you manage the next review date for that document(calculated or manually)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to create 2 views.

Review60, make a clause with where [LastReview] is less or equal to [Today]+60

NoReviewDate where [LastReview] is ""

Answer (score 0):

First of all, To achieve this you need to make your "Next review date" column as calculated column.

Use following formula to create "Next review date" and return the field as "date and time":

```
=  [Last review date] + 60
```

Then use following filter while creating your views:

1. **Show documents due for review(Next 60 days from today)**:

   `Next review date is greater than [Today]`

   `AND`

   `Next review date is less than [Today]+60`

**Note**: Do not add space between `[Today]`, `+`, and `60`.

2. **Show documents due for review(60 days from last review date)**:

   `Next review date is greater than [Today]`

   `AND`

   `last review date is less than [Today]`
3. **Show documents that don't have last review date**:

   `last review date is equal to`

**Note**: Keep the textbox below `is equal to` blank.

Comment: have you tried this?